# EntityManager.close() Not Closing The Connections to Database Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jpa

Here is my JPA Utill Class....

```
private static Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(JPAUtil.class);
private static EntityManager entityManager = null;
private static final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> threadLocal;

private static EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

static 
{
    try {

            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("XYZ");
            threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>();

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        logger.info("JPAUtil Exception",ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    try {
             entityManager = threadLocal.get();

        if (entityManager == null ||  !entityManager.isOpen()) {

            JPAUtil.entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
            threadLocal.set(entityManager);

        }else if(!emf.isOpen())
        {
             entityManager = threadLocal.get();
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("XYZ");
            JPAUtil.entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
            threadLocal.set(entityManager);
        }
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        logger.info("JPAUtil Exception",ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
    return JPAUtil.entityManager;
}

public static void closeEntityManager() {
    EntityManager entityManager = threadLocal.get();
    if (entityManager != null) {
        entityManager.close();
        threadLocal.set(null);
    }

    }
public static void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
    emf.close();
    }

public static void commit() {
    if (!entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()){
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    }
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
public static void rollback() {
    if (!entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()){
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    }
    entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
}
```

And After each and every transactions i am closing entitymanager....with

finally block...and later i came to Know that even in select query we need to

begin transaction and commit it...so i did try that in my application Home

page Just executing 2 select query and in the server mysql is Occupying the memory the most....with the eclipse MAT i Anallise the Memory Leak....

[image: MAT Result]

As per my understanding since i am using tomcat i cant do connection pooling..and we will be moving to jboss...but till the i would like to patch this....any help would be appreciated :) :)

Comment: You can use Tomcat with any JPA implementation like Hibernate or JBoss and of course you can use connection pooling within it. Closing `EntityManager` just makes all entities related to it unmanaged, it doesn't close connections in common case.

Comment: How can i use connection polling in Tomcat its not a JEE server Right...??

Comment: Hibernate, for instance, supports connection pooling and can be used as library even for non-JEE applications

Comment: On separate note I've got to say that that entity manager handling code looks pretty messy.  There are like three or four different places where an entity manager is being possibly created and to make things worse in static contexts.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo You mean in else if condition where iam creating EMF...and entitymanager :) :)???

Comment: Just a note: your code is not thread-safe. You shouldn't have a static field entityManager. Make it a local variable.